# Flask table only shows first line from Python list, for loop not working on rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, html-table

Newbie here.  Have a problem that is frustrating me.  I have a flask table is supposed to display a list from python, but it's only displaying the first row within the python list.

This is what the python list output looks like when I run the py script in visual studio code.

```
[('location 123', 'Hello Street', 'Los Angeles', 1.0, 40, 3, '2021-08-28T02:28:21.000000Z')]
[('location xyz', 'Beta Rd', 'Burlington', 1.0, 40, 2, '2021-08-28T00:30:36.000000Z')]
[('location abc', 'Alpha Ave', 'Seattle', 1.0, 40, 0, '2021-08-25T03:53:26.000000Z')]
```

The rows are dynamic so not every list will have a set amount.

The first row appears correct, along with the headers and everything lines up.  But I can't get the additional rows to show up.

here's the main.py line that sets the output

```
return render_template("result.html", headings=headings, output=city_details())
```

here is my result.html file

```
  <body>
  
    <h1>Results</h1>

    <table class="table">
      <tr class="table__header">
        {% for header in headings %}
        <th class="table__cell">{{ header }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>

      {% for row in output %}
      <tr class="table__row">
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td class="table__cell">{{cell}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
```

Here's part of the python script that sets the list

```
for details in data:
   location = details['location']
   street = details['street']
   city = details['city']
   scale = details['scale']
   etc...
   city_details = location, street, city, scale
   total_details = [city_details]
   return total_details
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong with my table for loop?  Or is my list done incorrectly?  I'm guessing it's something really simple I'm overlooking but I can't figure it out and driving myself nuts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intent is to process all of the details in data, his loop terminates early.

```
for details in data:
    ...
    return total_details
```

Answer (score 0):

The bit of your code that you showed is equivalent to

```
details = data[0]
location = details['location']
street = details['street']
city = details['city']
scale = details['scale']
# ... any additional processing ...
city_details = location, street, city, scale
total_details = [city_details]
return total_details
```

because you did an unconditional return inside the loop.

I would write a separate function that turns `details` into `city_details` and then use a list comprehension:

```
# earlier in your code, add this top-level function:
def make_table_row(details):
    location = details['location']
    street = details['street']
    city = details['city']
    scale = details['scale']
    # ... any additional processing ...
    return location, street, city, scale

# replace your original loop with this:
return [make_table_row(details) for details in data]
```